# Accessing Oculus Go trackpad axis data with A-Frame

Tags: aframe, oculus

I am using A-Frame (current master build), and my goal is to determine the location being touched on an Oculus Go controller. (This is not for moving the camera, so the movement-controls component will not help in this situation.) I have set up a scene containing a text object so that I can view the data while testing on the Oculus Go.

The relevant parts of the scene are:

```
<a-scene>    
    <a-entity id="textArea" text="data will be displayed here"> </a-entity>
    <a-entity oculus-go-controls updater> </a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

I am also using the following component, set up to display the data sent to the event handler:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('updater', {

init: function()
{
    let textArea = document.querySelector('#textArea');

    this.el.addEventListener("axismove", function(event)
    {
        textArea.setAttribute("text", "value", "axismove: " + JSON.stringify(event) );
    });     
}
```

});

However, after moving my thumb on the trackpad, the text object reads:

```
axismove: {'isTrusted': false}
```

My understanding based on https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/tracked-controls.html is that there should be axis data passed in the event. How can I access the axis information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oculus Go is only supported in the master branch until 0.9.0 ships but you can use it now by pointing your script tag to https://rawgit.com/aframevr/aframe/6888165/dist/aframe-master.min.js

Use the [oculus-go-controls component](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/docs/components/oculus-go-controls.md) and listen for the `trackpadchanged` event. The axis values are in the event detail:

```
  controllerEl.addEventListener(‘trackpadchanged’, function (evt) {
   ...evt.detail...
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work either. I've uploaded your idea at https://glitch.com/edit/#!/join/3bb1e5c1-1cba-477f-b2a9-ee98ec1756c6 and testing with the Oculus Go, I still get the same message while listening for trackpadchanged events - the event data is only "isTrusted:false". Any other ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: My mistake - JSON.stringify doesn't work the way I thought it did. Changing my code snippet to read JSON.stringify(event.detail) shows me the information I needed. Thanks for your help!